# Eclipse suddenly doesn't like my overrides

Tags: android, onclick, adapter

Seemingly out of no where, I launch Eclipse, start coding, and I have a ton of errors, all relating to me overriding functions of some base classes (the onclicks, the adapters, etc).  I remove the overrides and the functionality still works but I have no clue why this happened suddenly.  I'm worried it could cause bigger issues.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild your code?

Comment: Have you tried just cleaning the project? (Project -> Clean...)

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761888/override-annotation-error-android-prefs/4762107#4762107) ; maybe this helps

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance that , you are using Java 1.5 , there is some clash is Java 1.5 and 1.6 regarding override.

override should not have any problem in Java 1.6 I guess,

But if you want to build in command line , We have to use Java 1.5 at that time override gives problem while compiling.

Hope this might help.

If you want to see , which one you are using, Under Eclipse,
Windows >> Preferences >> Java >> Compiler

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm using 1.6.