# Project @Override error

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [@Override annotation error (android prefs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761888/override-annotation-error-android-prefs)

I have imported a project into my Eclipse and opened it, but it shows many errors (all error result to: `remove @Override annotation`. But the thing, is that the project is too big and has many of @Override's written around it, so is there a fastest way to delete `ALL` the `@Override` annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the compliance level of that project to 1.6 should solve those errors:

```
Right click the project > Properties > Java Compiler > Change compiler compliance to 1.6 > Apply
```