# @Override annotation error in Eclipse, why can't I resolve this?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, annotations, overriding

I've already tried [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761888/override-annotation-error-android-prefs)...

However, this seems to have been resolved in the newer version of Eclipse, as it already was set to 1.6 (I've installed JRE 6 too). But Eclipse still throws an error that I can't set to ignore, apparently.

Here's a part of my code (copied from a learning Java for Android website, so it should work...).

```
private class RadioGroupInfo implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private RadioButton mLastChecked;
    private String mNewSelectionMessageTemplate;
    private String mChangedSelectionMessageTemplate;

    public RadioGroupInfo() {
        mNewSelectionMessageTemplate = getString(R.string.new_selection_message_template);
        mChangedSelectionMessageTemplate = getString(R.string.changed_selection_message_template);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int CheckedId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Throws this error:

```
The method onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup, int) of type ButtonActivity.RadioGroupInfo must override or implement a supertype method
```

Comment: Check your imports. Are you importing `OnCheckedChangeListener` from somewhere other than [`RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html)?

Comment: Whats your Java version ?

Comment: That was it, Eclipse defaultly imported from CompoundButton instead of RadioGroup... X_X You can set it as an answer if you want the rep, you were faster than the other guy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your imports. Are you importing `OnCheckedChangeListener` from somewhere other than [RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html)?